# How can I get different types of notification?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I don't know how to send different types of notification to the device from Firebase cloud function in index.js I want to send (comments notification)(like notification).

I am using this code to get following notification to device but I don't know how to get other.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);   
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/notification/{user_id}/{notification_id}').onWrite((change, context) => {
const user_id = context.params.user_id;
const notification_id = context.params.notification_id;
console.log('We have a notification to send to  : ', user_id);
const fromUser = admin.database().ref(`/notification/${user_id}/${notification_id}`).once('value');
return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {
        const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;
        const from_message = fromUserResult.val().message;
        console.log('You have new notification from  : ', from_user_id);
const userQuery = admin.database().ref(`users/${from_user_id}/username`).once('value');
const deviceToken = admin.database().ref(`users/${user_id}/device_token`).once('value');

return Promise.all([userQuery,deviceToken]).then(result =>{
const userName = result[0].val();
const token_id = result[1].val();

  const payload1 = {
    notification:{
      title: "some is following you",
      body: `${userName} is following you`,
      icon: "default",
      click_action : "alpha.noname_TARGET_NOTFICATION"
    },
    data:{
       from_user_id:from_user_id
    }
  };
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload1).then(result=>{
console.log("notification sent");

});

})
.then(response => {
    console.log('This was the notification Feature');
    return true;
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
  //response.status(500).send(error);
  //any other error treatment
});

  });
});
```

Comment: think of it this way. if you have 3 buttons next to eachother, when u click on one of those buttons, it sends a string value to the cloud. the button next to it will do the same but have a different value. so instead of hard coding "some is following you", you insert the value being passed in by the request. request.like_string for example.

Comment: you are telling that I should create a string in my android studio project  "some one is following you " and pass it to the server to diplay that notification

Comment: I have on click_action ...what about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change what you are sending to the /notification/${user_id}/${notification_id} node to include fields that will let you identify and create different notifications in the cloud function.

For example, you could add a type field and then:

```
return fromUser.then(fromUserResult => {
    const from_user_id = fromUserResult.val().from;
    const from_message = fromUserResult.val().message;
    const from_type = fromUserResult.val().type;
```

Then you could build your notification based on type:

```
if(from_type === NOTIFICATION_FOLLOW){
   payload1 = {
    notification:{
      title: "some is following you",
      body: `${userName} is following you`,
      icon: "default",
      click_action : "alpha.noname_TARGET_NOTFICATION"
    },
    data:{
       from_user_id:from_user_id
    }
  };
}else{
  //set payload1 for a different notification
}
```

Add whatever fields are necessary for your payload and extend the control structure as needed.

Comment: how can I return  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload1)

Comment: should I return this after each payload

Comment: If you declare var payload1 before the conditional statements, then you can assign it based on each condition.  Then you won't need to change your return statement, just make sure it is after the conditional.